# Borel structures in a non-separable topological space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and assume $\tau_0\subset 2^{X}$ forms a topological base of minimal cardinality for $\tau$. Let us denote $M$ and $M_0$  by the sigma algebras generated by $\tau$ and $\tau_0$ respectively.

Q. Does there exist any non-separable topological space $X$ for which $M=M_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be an uncountable set and $\tau$ be the cocountable topology.  Then for any basis for $\tau$, any open set is a union of only countably many basis sets (since as soon as you have one nonempty basis set, you're only missing countably many points).  Thus $M=M_0$ for any basis.  But $X$ is not separable, since any countable subset is closed.

Comment: The discrete topology on the natural numbers is separable, but every countable set is closed.

Comment: Right, but in this case a countable set cannot be the whole space.

Comment: To show it has no countable basis, you can assume by contradiction that there is one of the form $\{X\setminus C_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and note that for $y\in X\setminus\bigcup_n C_n$, the open set $X\setminus\{y\}$ can not be a union of elements of such a basis.

Comment: You don't actually have to show it has no countable basis (though of course that is true).  What I wrote just directly shows that for any basis, every open set is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the basis.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread that part.